# ¿Cómo agrego un margin top en android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, component, margin

Tengo dos componentes, un mapView y un TextView, necesito que el mapView se coloque desde la posición 0,0 y tome el 100% del ancho de la pantalla y el 80% del alto de la pantalla (cosa que ya se hace), del otro lado tengo un TextView que necesito que tenga el 100% del ancho, 20% del alto (cosa que ya se hace) y un margin top del 80% para que se quede acomodado debajo el mapView. He hecho este código simple pero no sirve la parte del margin top del TextView:

```
// Obtén las dimensiones de la pantalla
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

// Define los porcentajes de ancho y alto deseados
int cienPorciento = 100;
int ochentaPorciento = 80;
int veintePorciento = 20;

// Calcula los tamaños en píxeles según los porcentajes
int widthPixels100 = (int) (screenWidth * (cienPorciento / 100.0));
int heightPixels80 = (int) (screenHeight * (ochentaPorciento / 100.0));
int heightPixels20 = (int) (screenHeight * (veintePorciento / 100.0));

// Asignamos los componentes
fondo = findViewById(R.id.fondoTextos);
mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);

// Asignamos ancho y alto al mapView
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsMap = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(widthPixels100, heightPixels80);
layoutParamsMap.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
mapView.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsMap);

// Asignamos ancho y alto al TextView
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsFondo = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(widthPixels100, heightPixels20);
layoutParamsFondo.setMargins(0, heightPixels80, 0, 0);
fondo.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsFondo);
```

Tambien ya intente con solo la propiedad:

```
layoutParamsFondo.topMargin = heightPixels80;
```

Pero de igual manera no funciona.
Dejo aquí una imagen de como luce mi app hasta el momento.

[image: Error en la app]

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionarlo lo hice desde código de XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="703dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fondoTextos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="182dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/mapView"
            android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
            android:background="#673AB7"
            android:text="Ernesto Lomar"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Solucionado]